# How to check if letter in a string appear in another string in the same order

Tags: python

I would love to check if the letters from a text appear in another text in the same order.

```
text    "Ce"
name    "Arsenic"
Answer   False


for x in text: 
    if x.lower() not in name.lower():
        return False
```

I would like that the order is checked too so that the elements appear in the same order in the other string : True else False.

At the moment my code only checks if the letters also appear in the string but not if they are in the same order.

Comment: `print(text.lower() in name.lower()) # False`

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean regarding "order"? Do you mean the text starts and the beginning of `name`, or another location in the string?

Answer (score 3):

i assume your "in order" means the character match in order. In your example text "Ce" name Arsenic should return False and should return True if text is "eC" instead.

first we check if all the character are inside the matching text, if yes, we further check if the matching index are in order, else we just return False

```
def check_text(text, name):
    name_lower = name.lower()
    if all(x in name_lower for x in text.lower()):
        char_index = [name_lower.index(x) for x in text.lower()]
        return char_index == sorted(char_index)
    else:
        return False


>>> check_text("Ce", "Arsenic")
False
>>> check_text("eC", "Arsenic")
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you want to check if `text` is contained in `name`. So instead of doing it at the character by character level (i.e. if all characters in text appears in name, the way that you are doing now), use the `in` operator on the two strings to check if `text` is `in` `name`.

i.e.
`return text.lower() in name.lower()`

see https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-see-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to avoid iterating through each letter of the word.

```
if any(text in name for text in text_collection):
    print(text)
```

This would check the whole string of `text` against a string in `name`. This is assuming that text_collection has more than one entry. Otherwise just use `if any(text in name):` See the official documentation of [any here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

Comment: If this helped you, please accept this answer as a solution. Otherwise let me know what issues you still have.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple

```
text = "Au"
name = "Gold"
text.lower() in name.lower()
False

text = "C"
name = "Carbon"
text.lower() in name.lower()
True
```